# OpenCOBOL Static Linking Multiple .cob Files

Tags: windows, compiler-errors, compilation, cobol, gnucobol

I am trying to statically link two COBOL files together using GnuCobol (Windows 10) following the example listed here: https://open-cobol.sourceforge.io/historical/open-cobol/Static-Linking.html but cannot seem to get it to work.

I am running the following:

```
cobc -free -c InterpFunc.cob
cobc -free -c -fmain Integrator.cob 
cobc -x -o .\\dist\\integrator Integrator.o InterpFunc.o
```

The '.o' files compile correctly, but the binary never builds with the following errors:

```
H:\Programs\COBAL\cobc\bin\cobc.exe: unrecognized option '-fmain'
h:/programs/cobal/cobc/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../libmingw32.a(main.o):(.text.startup+0xa0): undefined reference to `WinMain@16'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
The terminal process terminated with exit code: 1
```

I have tried a few different things such as leaving out the '-fmain' or leaving out the '-x', but all seem to produce different errors.

Is this perhaps an issue with my compiler/system setup or am I misunderstanding how to statically link files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm quite sure you do not use a compiler matching that old documentation (having "historical" in its URL). I'm quite sure it'll work the way the [current manual](https://open-cobol.sourceforge.io/doc/gnucobol.html#Static-linking) says:

> The easiest way of combining multiple files is to compile them into a single executable.
>
> One way is to compile all the files in one command:
>
> ```
> $ cobc -x -o prog main.cob subr1.cob subr2.cob
> ```
>
> Another way is to compile each file with the option -c, and link them at the end. > The top-level program must be compiled with the option -x.
>
> ```
> $ cobc -c subr1.cob
> $ cobc -c subr2.cob
> $ cobc -c -x main.cob
> $ cobc -x -o prog main.o subr1.o subr2.o
> ```